# Create an object in VB.Net to use in VBA

Tags: vba, vb.net, amazon-s3

Firstly, I'm quite new to this so be gentle!

I am trying to create a class/object in VB.net for use in vba.  I have used Gary Whitcher's code from the bottom of this post:

[Sample vb.net code to upload file to Amazon S3 storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21428688/sample-vb-net-code-to-upload-file-to-amazon-s3-storage)

I have created a class in Visual Studio and managed to get it to output a TLB file which i can import to VBA in Excel.

I can then use the object in VBA to create a new folder in the S3 storage system however I am running into problems when using the 'AddFileToFolder' method.

I have had to edit Gary's code a little to get it to compile in VS, the edited version is below.

```
Imports Amazon.S3
Imports Amazon.S3.Model
Imports Amazon
Imports Amazon.S3.Util
Imports System.Collections.ObjectModel
Imports System.IO

Public Class aws_s3

Const AWS_ACCESS_KEY As String = "AccessKey" 'is set to MY actual key
Const AWS_SECRET_KEY As String = "SecretKey" 'is set to MY actual key


Private Property s3Client As IAmazonS3

Sub New()
    Try
        s3Client = New AmazonS3Client(AWS_ACCESS_KEY, AWS_SECRET_KEY, RegionEndpoint.USEast1)
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try

End Sub


Public Function CreateFolder(bucketName As String, folderName() As String) As String
    Dim returnval As String = ""
    Try
        Try
            Dim folderKey As String = ""
            If Not AmazonS3Util.DoesS3BucketExist(s3Client, bucketName) Then
                returnval = "Bucket does not exist"
            Else
                For i = 0 To folderName.Length - 1
                    folderKey += folderName(i) & "/"

                Next
                ' folderKey = folderKey & "/"    'end the folder name with "/"
                Dim request As PutObjectRequest = New PutObjectRequest()
                request.BucketName = bucketName
                request.StorageClass = S3StorageClass.Standard
                request.ServerSideEncryptionMethod = ServerSideEncryptionMethod.None
                ' request.CannedACL = S3CannedACL.BucketOwnerFullControl
                request.Key = folderKey
                request.ContentBody = String.Empty
                s3Client.PutObject(request)
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            returnval = ex.Message
        End Try
    Catch ex As AmazonS3Exception
        returnval = ex.Message
    End Try
    Return returnval
End Function
Public Function AddFileToFolder(FileName As String, bucketName As String, folderName As String) As String
    Dim returnval As String = ""
    Try
        Try
            If Not AmazonS3Util.DoesS3BucketExist(s3Client, bucketName) Then
                Dim fname() As String = folderName.Split("/")
                CreateFolder(bucketName, fname)
            Else
                Dim path As String = FileName
                Dim file As FileInfo = New FileInfo(path)

                Dim key As String = String.Format("{0}/{1}", folderName, file.Name)
                Dim por As PutObjectRequest = New PutObjectRequest()
                por.BucketName = bucketName
                por.StorageClass = S3StorageClass.Standard
                por.ServerSideEncryptionMethod = ServerSideEncryptionMethod.None
                por.CannedACL = S3CannedACL.PublicRead
                por.Key = key
                por.InputStream = file.OpenRead()
                s3Client.PutObject(por)
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            returnval = ex.Message
        End Try
    Catch ex As AmazonS3Exception
        returnval = ex.Message
    End Try
    Return returnval & " dll"
End Function
```

End Class

Using VBA, I have created the above object and can successfully execute CreateFolder but when executing addfiletofolder i get the error "Class does not support automation or does not support expected interface"

the VBA code looks like this:

```
Dim aws As AWS_S3
Dim Result As String
Dim UploadFile As String

UploadFile = "C:\Zipped Builds\Hinchley Legion.zip"

Set aws = New AWS_S3

Dim fld(1) As String
fld(0) = "folder"
fld(1) = "subfolder"

Result = aws.CreateFolder("nsmcustomercontent", fld)

If Result <> "" Then GoTo errHandle

Result = aws.AddFileToFolder(UploadFile, "nsmcustomercontent", fld)

If Result <> "" Then GoTo errHandle

Exit Sub

errHandle:
    MsgBox Result


End Sub
```

I'm guessing from the fact that CreateFolder works fine but AddFileToFolder doesn't, there is a problem in the class as created in VS, missing a dependancy or something?

Comment: So I've managed to narrow down the problem.  The error is only thrown when I pass the fld variable, which is an array.  The problem is not encountered if i pass it a single element from the array, e.g. fld(0)

Comment: The `AddFileToFolder` function does not expect a String array. It takes a String which can contain a `/` as a delimiter. So, instead of passing an array `["folder", "subfolder"]` ... try passing a String `"folder/subfolder"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Anu6is, that was indeed the problem.  The author of the class had wrote the following for usage which had thrown me off:

ADD FILE TO FOLDER

```
            Dim fld(1) As String                 
            fld(0) = <foldername>
            fld(1) = <subfoldername>
            'List each sub folder as an element in array
            Dim rtrn As String = aws.AddFileToFolder(<local file name>,<bucketname>, fld)
```

I need to get better at reading VB.Net i think!  Many thanks for your quick reply, much appreciated.